# How to properly specify indices for a four-sided pyramid in WebGL?"

Tags: javascript, html, graphics, geometry, webgl

I am trying to create a 4-sided pyramid in WebGL where each face is a different color and I believe I'm running into issues with the indices. From my understanding, if I specify an indexed array, WebGL should be drawing a line between the corresponding vertices. I believe my code has all the necessary lines covered but I just can't get the pyramid to form correctly.

If someone could take a look at my code and help me figure out where I'm going wrong, that would be greatly appreciated!

Javascript code:

```
"use strict";

var canvas;
var gl;

var numPositions = 12;

var positions = [];
var colors = [];

var xAxis = 0;
var yAxis = 1;
var zAxis = 2;

var axis = 0;
var theta = [0, 0, 0];

var thetaLoc;

window.onload = function init()
{
    canvas = document.getElementById("gl-canvas");

    gl = canvas.getContext('webgl2');
    if (!gl) alert("WebGL 2.0 isn't available");

    colorPyramid();

    gl.viewport(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    gl.clearColor(1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0);

    gl.enable(gl.DEPTH_TEST);

    //
    //  Load shaders and initialize attribute buffers
    //
    var program = initShaders(gl, "vertex-shader", "fragment-shader");
    gl.useProgram(program);

    var cBuffer = gl.createBuffer();
    gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, cBuffer);
    gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, flatten(colors), gl.STATIC_DRAW);

    var colorLoc = gl.getAttribLocation( program, "aColor" );
    gl.vertexAttribPointer( colorLoc, 4, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0 );
    gl.enableVertexAttribArray( colorLoc );

    var vBuffer = gl.createBuffer();
    gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, vBuffer);
    gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, flatten(positions), gl.STATIC_DRAW);


    var positionLoc = gl.getAttribLocation(program, "aPosition");
    gl.vertexAttribPointer(positionLoc, 4, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0);
    gl.enableVertexAttribArray(positionLoc);

    thetaLoc = gl.getUniformLocation(program, "uTheta");

    //event listeners for buttons

    document.getElementById( "xButton" ).onclick = function () {
        axis = xAxis;
    };
    document.getElementById( "yButton" ).onclick = function () {
        axis = yAxis;
    };
    document.getElementById( "zButton" ).onclick = function () {
        axis = zAxis;
    };

    render();
}

function colorPyramid()
{
    triple(0, 3, 2); //base
    triple(2, 0, 1); 
    triple(3, 1, 2); 
    triple(0, 1, 3); 
}

function triple(a, b, c)
{
    var vertices = [
        vec3(0.5, -0.2722, 0.2886),
        vec3(0.0, -0.2772, -0.5773),
        vec3(-0.5, -0.2722, 0.2886),
        vec3(0.0, 0.5443, 0.0)
    ];

    var vertexColors = [
        vec4(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0),  // black
        vec4(1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0),  // red
        vec4(0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0),  // green
        vec4(0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0)  // blue
    ];

    // We need to parition the quad into two triangles in order for
    // WebGL to be able to render it.  In this case, we create two
    // triangles from the quad indices

    //vertex color assigned by the index of the vertex

    var indices = [a, b, c];

    for ( var i = 0; i < indices.length; ++i ) {
        positions.push( vertices[indices[i]] );
        //colors.push( vertexColors[indices[i]] );

        // for solid colored faces use
        colors.push(vertexColors[a]);
    }
}

function render()
{
    gl.clear( gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | gl.DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

    theta[axis] += 2.0;
    gl.uniform3fv(thetaLoc, theta);

    gl.drawArrays(gl.TRIANGLES, 0, numPositions);
    requestAnimationFrame(render);
}
```

I don't think the issue is my HTML code, but it never hurts to include it!

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<script id="vertex-shader" type="x-shader/x-vertex">
#version 300 es

in  vec4 aPosition;
in  vec4 aColor;
out vec4 vColor;

uniform vec3 uTheta;

void main()
{
    // Compute the sines and cosines of theta for each of
    //   the three axes in one computation.
    vec3 angles = radians(uTheta);
    vec3 c = cos(angles);
    vec3 s = sin(angles);

    // Remeber: thse matrices are column-major
    mat4 rx = mat4(1.0,  0.0,  0.0, 0.0,
            0.0,  c.x,  s.x, 0.0,
            0.0, -s.x,  c.x, 0.0,
            0.0,  0.0,  0.0, 1.0);

    mat4 ry = mat4(c.y, 0.0, -s.y, 0.0,
            0.0, 1.0,  0.0, 0.0,
            s.y, 0.0,  c.y, 0.0,
            0.0, 0.0,  0.0, 1.0);


    mat4 rz = mat4(c.z, s.z, 0.0, 0.0,
            -s.z,  c.z, 0.0, 0.0,
            0.0,  0.0, 1.0, 0.0,
            0.0,  0.0, 0.0, 1.0);

    vColor = aColor;
    gl_Position = rz * ry * rx * aPosition;
    gl_Position.z = -gl_Position.z;
}
</script>

<script id="fragment-shader" type="x-shader/x-fragment">
#version 300 es

precision mediump float;

in vec4 vColor;
out vec4 fColor;

void
main()
{
    fColor = vColor;
}
</script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://interactivecomputergraphics.com/Code/Common/utility.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://interactivecomputergraphics.com/Code/Common/initShaders.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://interactivecomputergraphics.com/Code/Common/MV.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="ASPyramid.js"></script>

<body>
<canvas id="gl-canvas" width="512" height="512">
Oops ... your browser doesn't support the HTML5 canvas element
</canvas>

<br/>

<button id= "xButton">Rotate X</button>
<button id= "yButton">Rotate Y</button>
<button id= "zButton">Rotate Z</button>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Ended up figuring out the issue with the help of a nice Redditor. I forgot to update the vertexAttribPointer for positionLoc to 3 instead of 4. The pyramid renders properly now.